# Why is webpage body appearing to be blank?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

I am learning basic crud operations in React, and ran into this problem. In the components, I am primarily expecting to see one word in each page. But when I am starting the react app, pages appear to be blank. I guess I missed something about `react-router` or r`eact-router-dom`. Codes are given here.

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import books from "./components/books.jsx";
import add from "./components/add.jsx";
import update from "./components/update.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element= {<books />} />
          <Route path="/add" element= {<add />} />
          <Route path="/update" element= {<update />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### books.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const books = () => {
  return (
    <div>books</div>
  )
}

export default books;
```

### add.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const add = () => {
  return (
    <div>add</div>
  )
}

export default add;
```

### update.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const update = () => {
  return (
    <div>Update</div>
  )
}

export default update;
```

### Sub-directories and files in client directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15CT1.png)

Codes may seem incomplete as I have encountered this problem at the halfway. I tried some fixes from youtube and google, but could not right it.

Comment: Do you try to `F12` to see the console? Maybe have some error?

Answer (score 2):

React components are Capitalized. From [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized):

> ### User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized
>
> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
> built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string
> `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start
> with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to
> `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or
> imported in your JavaScript file.

By using `<book />` React assumes this is an HTML element and doesn't create a React element from your component code.

```
import React from "react";

const Books = () => {
  return (
    <div>books</div>
  )
}

export default Books;
```

```
import Books from "./components/books.jsx";
import Add from "./components/add.jsx";
import Update from "./components/update.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Books />} />
          <Route path="/add" element={<Add />} />
          <Route path="/update" element={<Update />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why does it matter?

Comment: @ArnabDasJoy I've updated the answer to include more detail.